# jQuery multiple selector and multiple values for p content

Tags: jquery

I have this code (below) that is working fine when

contains 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.  But I wanted to use it for an unlimited option, when the number inside

is 10 or more to show a generic result for any number above 9.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(2)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9313;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(3)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9314;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(4)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9315;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(5)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9316;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(6)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9317;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(7)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9318;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(8)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9319;</span>");
    $('#[invoicenum] p:contains(9)').before("<span class='bynum'>&#9320;</span>");
    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try to read about for loop in JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: What value does your `p` have? Is it only number or there is additional text also.

Comment: I am sorry, Maybe I didn't explain the request very well.  All your answers may work, but they will change how the page is actually working right now, and it will be a nightmare for me, because the main issue I have is that some date (as the [invoicenum], is automatically generated by the hosting, so I need to use it that way).

Comment: I am sorry, Maybe I didn't explain the request very well.  All your answers may work, but the main issue I have is that some date automatically generated by the hosting,  [invoicenum] as well as the number contained in p are variables that the hosting will load in different invoices at the same time. I can't change it. The code is working fine.

What I would really like to have is to add an extra line after the last one, to handle a single action for all number >9, so it will show the same special character for all other possible numbers.

Comment: P will be also a number (always, no text) that will be generated by the hosting, and different from invoice to invoice (basically, <p> contains the number of items for each product).  Again, thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a associative array with the key and the value.

And then make first loop for all your Paragraph

And then make another loop for your array and check if you find the key.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var arrayCheck = {
      2: '&#9313;',
      3: '&#9314;',
      4: '&#9315;',
      5: '&#9316;'
    }
    
    $('#invoicenum p').each(function(index, p) {
      var currentParagraph = $(this);
      $.each(arrayCheck, function(key, value){
        if ($(currentParagraph).text().indexOf(key) > -1) {
          $(currentParagraph).before("<span class='bynum'>" + value + "</span>");
        }
      });
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invoicenum">
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Or like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var arrayCheck = [2, 3, 4, 5];
    
    $('#invoicenum p').each(function(index, p) {
      var currentParagraph = $(this);
      $.each(arrayCheck, function(key, value){
        if ($(currentParagraph).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
          $(currentParagraph).before("<span class='bynum'>&#931" + (value + 1) + "</span>");
        }
      });
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invoicenum">
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your selector `#[invoicenum]` is not valid. It should not have `[]`.

Use `$('#invoicenum p')` and loop over each object and fetch number value with regex `.match(/\d+/)`. This will work even if you have any text included inside `p`.

Check comments in code for explanation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#invoicenum p').each(function(index, item) {
    // convert item to jquery object
    item = $(item);
    // find numbers from p
    var num = item.text().match(/\d+/);
    // intial number to get number between 2 and 9
    var spanNum = 9311;

    // if num is not null and it contains value then proceed
    if (num && num.length > 0) {
      // get number value in val object
      val = parseInt(num[0]);

      // if values is between 2 & 9
      if (val >= 2 && val <= 9) {
        item.before("<span class='bynum'>&#" + (spanNum + val) + ";</span>");
      } else if (val > 9) {
        // generic value for value above 9        
        item.before("<span class='bynum'>&#9321;</span>");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='invoicenum'>
  <p>text 2</p>
  <p>text 6</p>
  <p>text 9</p>
  <p>text 10</p>
  <p>text 20</p>
</div>
```